# React function not using current state when button clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I am creating a form in React that uses dynamically added fieldsets for contacts that I am adding through using state. These fieldsets have a button to remove the fieldset if the user wishes to. However when I click the remove button and display the state value, I am getting a different albeit consistent result, which when filtering is not giving proper results.

Here are bits of the code I am using:

```
const [insertContactForm, setInsertContactForm] = useState([]);
const [position, setPosition] = useState(0);
```

then to add the form component when the 'add contact' button is clicked:

```
const handleAddContactForm = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setPosition(position + 1);
        setInsertContactForm([...insertContactForm, <div key={position}><button onClick={(e) => {handleContactFormRemove(e, position)}}>-</button><ContactForm contactNumber={position} /></div>]);
    }
```

To see what data was passed to the remove contact form function:

```
const handleContactFormRemove = (e, position) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(position);
        console.log(insertContactForm)
    }
```

When I click on each remove button, I am getting an array returned that differs from the current state - for example, if I insert three contact forms and click on the first delete button, I am getting an empty array for the state; if I click on the second delete button, I get an array with the prior element, and on the third it returns an array with the two prior elements. How do I make sure I am getting the current state when I click the delete button? The position state always displays correctly, just FYI.

Thanks!

Comment: `setInsertContactForm([...insertContactForm, <button onClick={(e) => {handleContactFormRemove(e, position)}}>-</button>])` This means that the new `<button>` is created with the value of the `handleContactFormRemove` when that element was added. Since the removal handler closes over the `insertContactForm` state variable, the button's event handler always refers to the state it had when it was created.

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that the button refers to the current state then? Thanks!

Comment: I would probably try to avoid storing the `<button>-</button><ContactForm />` in state entirely. Maybe store an array of positions instead (in addition to the existing position state to keep track of the last one added and avoid duplicates) and use that to render the buttons/ContactForms.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm generating the jsx based on the position array and it appears that I am getting the behavior expected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
setInsertContactForm([...insertContactForm, (
  <div key={position}>
    <button onClick={(e) => {handleContactFormRemove(e, position)}}>-</button>
    <ContactForm contactNumber={position} />
  </div>
)]);
```

will add the elements to state as expected, but the button's click handler won't ever be updated. It's set to the `handleContactFormRemove` function that is in scope within that specific render. In subsequent renders that function will be a new function that captures the new state, but it's still the old version of that function that runs when you click the button, because that's the version that was added as the onClick handler. That old version of the function captured the variables it had when it was defined, not the new versions of them that exist when the function reruns. This is only a problem because these buttons are saved as their own state, rather than as part of the render, so their properties are exactly the same as what they had when they were added in the `setInsertContactForm()` call, which would be the old `handleContactFormRemove()` function.

---

The simplest way around this would probably be to avoid using the buttons/ContactForms as state variables, and instead use an array of positions (in addition to the existing position state that would be used to reference the next value and avoid duplicates). Then you can use that array to create the buttons and ContactForms.

```
const [nextPosition, setNextPosition] = useState(0);
const [positions, setPositions] = useState([]);

const handleAddContactForm = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setNextPosition(nextPosition + 1);
  setPositions([...positions, nextPosition]);
}

const handleContactFormRemove = (e, positionToRemove) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(positionToRemove);
  console.log(positions)
}

return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={handleAddContactForm}>+</button>

    {positions.map((position) => (
      <div key={position}>
        <button onClick={(e) => {handleContactFormRemove(e, position)}}>-</button>
        <ContactForm contactNumber={position} />
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: This was very helpful. I was wrestling for hours with `useRef.current`, `useEffect`, and others to try and get these "add..." and "remove..." functions to keep track of the current state, all without success.

The only thing I'd add is how to handle the filter in the "...remove" function. Here was my solution:

`const handleQuestionDelete = (e, positionToRemove) => {
    // Filter out the one that we want to delete.
    const filteredPositions = positions.filter(position => {
      return position !== positionToRemove;
    });
    setPositions(filteredPositions);
  };`

Answer (score 0):

React State change is async so not necessarily you will get the state value immediately.
You can make use of useEffect with dependency to check if value change and do the operation